# Add Build Configuration Programmatically for a .sln

Tags: c#, visual-studio

**Q1:** I would like to ask if there is a way to add build configurations for a C# Solution programmatically?

I was able to read the .sln file and get its configurations thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30131059/1672701).

Sadly `ProjectCollection.GlobalProjectCollection` is kind of a getter only. I can read and get all kind of properties, but it lacks a `save` functionality.

---

I am aware a .sln file is a regular file (and it is possible to write to it directly, but I would trust a native API more):

<sub>{97C119BD-E435-490C-B955-06EA0AD3C08A}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU</sub>

<sub>{97C119BD-E435-490C-B955-06EA0AD3C08A}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU</sub>

**{97C119BD-E435-490C-B955-06EA0AD3C08A}.New Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU**

**{97C119BD-E435-490C-B955-06EA0AD3C08A}.New Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU**

**{97C119BD-E435-490C-B955-06EA0AD3C08A}.New Debug|Any CPU.Deploy.0 = Debug|Any CPU**

<sub>{97C119BD-E435-490C-B955-06EA0AD3C08A}.Observe Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU</sub>

<sub>{97C119BD-E435-490C-B955-06EA0AD3C08A}.Observe Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU</sub>

<sub>{97C119BD-E435-490C-B955-06EA0AD3C08A}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU</sub>

<sub>{97C119BD-E435-490C-B955-06EA0AD3C08A}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU</sub>

---

**Q2:** Why are there 3 rows of configuration statements for `New Debug`?

**Any CPU.Deploy.0** is present in a single project even though my solution has 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some considerable time on this task, I was able to automatically add Build Configurations to my Solution using the VS dll.

Here is some example code:

```
public void CustomSolutionConfiguration()
{
    var slnFile = Path.Combine(@"C:\Work\Dev\MvcConfigurations", @"MvcConfigurations.sln");

    //VisualStudio.DTE.14.0 this hardcoded string is VS version dependent!
    System.Type t = System.Type.GetTypeFromProgID("VisualStudio.DTE.14.0"); 
    object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(t, true);
    var dte = (DTE2)obj;
    Solution sln = dte.Solution;
    sln.Open(slnFile);
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    //Do stuff with the solution

    var projs = sln.Projects;
    var cnfManager = sln.Projects.Item(1).ConfigurationManager;   

    var slnCnfgCount = sln.SolutionBuild.SolutionConfigurations.Count;
    for (var tt = 1; tt <= slnCnfgCount; tt++)
    {   
         Console.WriteLine(sln.SolutionBuild.SolutionConfigurations.Item(tt).Name);
         var tmpItem = sln.SolutionBuild.SolutionConfigurations.Item(tt);
         var tmp = sln.SolutionBuild.SolutionConfigurations.Item(tt).SolutionContexts;
         //Do some test printing
         for (var tt2 = 1; tt2 <= tmp.Count; tt2++)
         {
             var tmp2 = tmp.Item(tt2);
             Console.Write(tmp2.ConfigurationName + ";  ");
         }

         Console.WriteLine();
     }

     sln.SaveAs(slnFile);
     Console.ReadLine();
}
```